# Failed to open stream? Image upload but are not echoing

Tags: php, html

I am working on upload file in php. i done it successfully but when i want to print it it give me error plz help me My php Script is below

```html
<?php
$target_dir = "C:\wamp\www\upload\upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
 
 if(copy($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $target_dir))
{
echo "Successful<BR/>";
echo "File Name :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']."<BR/>";
echo "File Size :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size']."<BR/>";
echo "File Type :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']."<BR/>";
echo "<img src=\"$target_dir\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
}
}
?>
```

following error occur

[image]

it should be print like this once it uploaded
[enter link description here](http://demos.click4knowledge.com/singleupload/)

Comment: `$target_file` contains an absolute server path to your image. In HTML, the image URL need to be either relative from the document root (/path/to/file) or an absolute with the hostname (http: //hostname/path/to/file).

Comment: error is in this line if(copy($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $target_dir))

Comment: Why do you have that `copy()` in the first place? You've already moved the file as `$target_file` with `move_uploaded_file()` just before? And as it is right now, if `move_uploaded_file()` fails, your code is still going to try to copy it, which will most likely fail as well, in that case.

Comment: so what should i do now?

Comment: Replace the `if (copy(...))` with something like: `if (is_file($target_file))` and then change `<img src="$target_file"...` to use a relative path (from the doc root to the uploaded picture) to the image instead of an absolute server path..

Comment: if i use relative path of particular image then how it will print new photo i will upload next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRy like this

```html
 if (is_file($target_file))
{
echo "Successful<BR/>";
echo "File Name :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']."<BR/>";
echo "File Size :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size']."<BR/>";
echo "File Type :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']."<BR/>";
echo "<img src=\"$target_file\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're copying a file that's not existing anymore..

```
//$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] doesn't exist anymore because YOU MOVED IT
copy($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $target_dir)
```

Instead of using $_FILE, if you want to copy.. you can do it like..

```
copy($target_file, $target_dir)
```

That variable 'target_file' is where you Moved your file right?

That should work.

Comment: it gives now this error ( ! ) Warning: copy(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\wamp\www\upload\index2.php on line 44

Comment: just change $target_dir to $target_dir.'/yourfilename.jpg'

Comment: if $target_dir already has directory separator at the end then no need to place "/" to it... you can use the CONSTANT variable DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }

    if(copy($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $target_dir))
{
echo "Successful<BR/>";
echo "File Name :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']."<BR/>";
echo "File Size :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size']."<BR/>";
echo "File Type :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']."<BR/>";
echo "<img src=\"$target_dir\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
}
```

to

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        echo "Successful<BR/>";
echo "File Name :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']."<BR/>";
echo "File Size :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size']."<BR/>";
echo "File Type :".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']."<BR/>";
echo "<img src=\"$target_dir\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
```

No need of `if(copy($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $target_dir))` because `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]['name']` is not a file, but the file is `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]`, and you have done it already